# Bounding box for multiple SVG paths

Tags: svg, bounding-box

I have some SVG paths which represent equations. There will be multiple on the canvas. I would like to pass all of these paths and get back grouped paths where each group represents a single equation.

[image]

1. Assumptions there is no overlap between the equations bounding boxes

After processing I should then be able to apply a bounding box to check the success the end result should be;

[image]

I already know  how to apply a bounding box to a set of points. I am specifically struggling with how to determine which set of points or paths should go into a single group.

For example I would not want it to give me a bounding box for the "y", "=", "m" e.t.c separately that would be of little use.

Comment: So basically what you want to have is a program that understands the semantic meaning of the paths?

Comment: A easy solution to your problem: adding a button that creates a new group on click. After click all the new paths are added to the last group created.

Comment: @ccprog it doesn't need to understand what's written. This is already possible with My script.

Comment: @enxaneta unfortunately that is not an option on this solution